# In C# it's better define object's attribute in its initialization or with dot notation?

Tags: c#

What is more efficent between this:

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass()
{
    name = "foo",
    color = "blue",
    number = 3
};
```

and this:

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass();
foo.name = "foo";
foo.color = "blue";
foo.number = 3;
```

Comment: _What is more efficent_ Why do you think they have different efficiency? They produce same IL code, that's why I don't think there are an _efficent_ issue.

Comment: What you mean by the word "Effective"? faster? compiler compiles the both to the same IL, so no difference

Comment: It would be more "efficient" with `=` instead of `:` :)

Comment: @SonerGönül - you might be interested [in this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1679780/314291) - see Eric and Luke's answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference between first and second is, that the second way won't create a temporary object (as explained here: [CA2000 - "out-of-school-junior-programmers"-mistakes or false positive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380279/ca2000-out-of-school-junior-programmers-mistakes-or-false-positive)) - so no problems, warning or errors when it comes to disposing `My Class`.

Comment: Thanks - this leads to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1679841/314291 - interesting.

Comment: yeah, indeed haha, had this (plus its resulting CA2000) problem a few weeks ago and could not explain why this might happen - now i know. hope this solved this question and your problem :)

Comment: Also, this means the linked duplicate is actually wrong, even in release mode. There seems to be an extra assignment with the initializer, to keep the observable state of `foo` consistent.